# Escaped characters in text area but not in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had some help on here to create this:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/ZTuDJ/38/

My problem comes from the fact that html is stripped out when putting the value of the responsibility field into the text area, but when adding it to the list it still has the HTML on. That means that if someone types in this:

```
<b>Testing</b>
```

When I type this in, I get this in the text area when it is stripped:

```
Testing
```

But in the list it still has the html tags so it looks like this:

> **Testing**

This is my code which puts it in the text are and the list:

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text() ).before("<li>"+lines+"</li>");
```

**My question:** How do I put the same stripped value which goes into the text area also into the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+"</li>");
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/40/